# How to convert an array all value without using foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array

I want to convert an array value without using any loop 
and i have an array something like this

```
Array
  (
[0] => Array
       (
        [month] => August
       )

[1] => Array
    (
        [month] => July
     )

[2] => Array
    (
        [month] => October
    )
)
```

I want to convert above array in to below format

```
Array
(
    [0] => August
    [1] => July
    [2] => October
)
```

Without using any loop

Comment: i have tried call_user_func_array , but its return only one value i want all

Comment: Just curious on why you would want to do this? It seems silly collapsing an array to create multiple arrays with a single string value inside it.

Comment: you have answer @Matt

Comment: I don't understand your result. That's not a single variable, it's 3 different variables.

Comment: Please explain what you are asking - it is not clear.

Comment: yes i want response in 3 different variables

Comment: What 3 variables? What if there aree more than 3 elements in the original array?

Comment: `$var1 = $array[0]; $var2 = $array[1]; $var3 = $array[2];`

Comment: I have a mysql query in which result is getting in the above array format and i want to convert that array in below array format and value is dyanamic

Comment: i want to print dynamic value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using PHP 5.5 or higher, you can use the [`array_column`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) function:

```
$new_array = array_column($array, 'month');
```

In older versions of PHP, you can use `array_map`

```
$new_array = array_map(function($x) { return $x['month']; }, $array);
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/tn2yTG)

Comment: I have a mysql query in which result is getting in the above array format and i want to convert that array in below array format and value is dyanamic –

Comment: The below array format is not an array. It's not anything. It's just the output of calling `print_r` on 3 different arrays.

Comment: Maybe what you want is `array("August", "July", "October")`?

Comment: yes, its output of calling print_r

Comment: yes i want array("August", "July", "October")?

Comment: I've edited my answer to show how to do it.

Comment: but how i get july value because  i have to print month value not 0,1,2

Comment: July value is `$new_array[1]`

Comment: See the demo I added.

Answer (score -1):

it's my code so plz change it.... and try this

```
 $a = array(0, 4, 5, 7);
// PHP 5.3+ anonmymous function.
$output = array_map(function($val) { return $val+1; }, $a);

print_r($output);
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 5
    [2] => 6
    [3] => 8
)
```

Edit by OP:

```
function doubleValues($a) {
  return array_map(function($val) { return $val * 2; }, $a);
}
```

Comment: How i change my code in to this format

Comment: What does this have to do with the question? He's not changing the values in the array.